# Java JTextField setPlaceholder not working

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

just a quick question but I have a little Gu set up which has a JFormattedTextField.  I want the text box for date entry and I want the textbox to show "yyyy-mm-dd".

When I use the following code it doesn't work:

```
<pre>dateFormatter = new MaskFormatter("####-##-##");
            dateFormatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
            //dateFormatter.setPlaceholder("yyyy-mm-dd");

            startDate = new JFormattedTextField  (dateFormatter);
            dateFormatter.getDisplayValue(startDate, "123");
            //startDate.addActionListener(this);
            startDate.addPropertyChangeListener("value", this
```

How do I modify the code to get it working?  I have tried a few different approaches and the above works if I just want to use the "_" as the PlaceholderCharacter but not when I try to set the placeholder as "yyyy-mm-yy".

Incidentally I'm using java 1.6.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Sounds more like you want "placeholder" support which is provided by the default API (SwingX has it), but I doubt you'd have much luck getting it to work with `JFormattedTextField` because it displays "text" all the time. A better solution might be to use some kind of date picker instead

Comment: Please note, that the format "yyyy-mm-dd" will present year-minute-day. Probably you need "yy-MM-dd" when you want to see year-month-day.

Comment: `I want the textbox to show "yyyy-mm-dd".` - I've never tried it with a JFormattedTextField but maybe the [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) class will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no placeholder in java , instead you can use mouse adapter interface,   onclick set textfiled.setText("");

```
textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
 {
      textArea.setText("..");
    } 
    }
```

:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html